# Safari issue - Dropdown Menu using AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, safari

I have installed a dropdown menu (in a php site) that makes use of Ajax functionality to populate the dropdown list.

It functions correctly in Chrome and Firefox, and NOT Safari.

In Safari it works;

- If the user tabs into the field;
- If the user double clicks the field, or clicks in the field and then outside the element.

The form code reads;

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.sel_field').focus(function(){

        $.ajax({
            url: 'GetClient.php',
            type: 'post',
            dataType: 'json',
            success:function(response){

                var len = response.length;

                $('#sel_user').empty();
                for( var i = 0; i<len; i++){
                    var id = response[i]['id'];
                    var name2 = response[i]['username'];
                    var name = response[i]['name'];
                    var mat = response[i]['Matter'];

                    $('#sel_user').append('<option value='+id+'> ClientID: '+id+' -  Name:   '+name+' : '+mat+'</option>');

                }
            }
        });
    });
});
```

```html
<tr>
    <td>
        Client ID <span style='font-size:10px'>(Press tab to enter)</span>
    </td>
    <td>
        <select  name='clientID' style='width:460px' class='form-control sel_field' id='sel_user' >
            <option value='0'> - Make A Selection -</option>
        </select>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

To start with you might try putting some quotes around the id you use for the value in the append line.

```
$('#sel_user').append('<option value="'+id+'"> ClientID: '+id+' -  Name:   '+name+' : '+mat+'</option>');
```

Not having that value quoted may confuse the Safari browser.

I would also change the echo at the bottom of your page for the table to this.  I find using single quotes for echoing html output to be more intuitive and allows you to use double quotes for the tag attributes.

```
echo 
'<tr>
  <td>
    Client ID <span style="font-size:10px">(Press tab to enter)</span>
  </td>
  <td>
    <select  name="clientID" style="width:460px" class="form-control sel_field" id="sel_user" >
      <option value="0"> - Make A Selection -</option>
    </select>
  </td>
</tr>';
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this instead:

```
$('.sel_field').on("keyup click", function(){
```

You may wanna set a loaded flag so you know your options are already loaded and should not be loaded again.

**Updated JS Code:**

```
var options_loaded = false;

$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.sel_field').on("keyup click", function(){
    if(options_loaded == true) return;
    $.ajax({
      url: 'GetClient.php',
      type: 'post',
      dataType: 'json',
      success: function(response) {
        var len = response.length;

        $('#sel_user').empty();
        for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
          var id = response[i]['id'];
          var name2 = response[i]['username'];
          var name = response[i]['name'];
          var mat = response[i]['Matter'];

          $('#sel_user').append('<option value=' + id + '> ClientID: ' + id + ' -  Name:   ' + name + ' : ' + mat + '</option>');
        }
        options_loaded = true;
      }
    });
  });

});
```

Comment: Updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks Karlo.  Still the same problem - working in Chrome but not Safari.